# Moved old Dot Net Nuke site to new server now get linkclick.aspx not found

Tags: c#, asp.net, dotnetnuke

I have recently moved a DNN site to a new hosting service. The site comes up fine but when I try to click on a link I get a /LinkClick.aspx not found (404) error.

I assume it has something to do with the handler for LinkClick.aspx and the fact that I am now running under .Net 4 rather then the .Net 2 the old site was running under.

What is the correct way to resolve this?

Comment: Have you tried running it under .net 2?  There is a setting in IIS to do that

Answer (score 2):

I got it to work by removing the runtimeVersion2.0 specification in the add handler line of the web.config.

```
<add name="LinkClickHandler" 
path="LinkClick.aspx" 
verb="*" 
type="DotNetNuke.Services.FileSystem.FileServerHandler, DotNetNuke"
preCondition="integratedMode" />

<add name="CaptchaHandler" 
path="*.captcha.aspx" 
verb="*" 
type="DotNetNuke.UI.WebControls.CaptchaHandler, DotNetNuke"
preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv2.0" />
```